# How do I Add a Google Play search icon to my Android App?

Tags: android, google-play

how can I add an icon to the Google Play search field when someone searches for my android application?

Here is an example of what I would like to do: http://s12.postimage.org/dcem3mnal/Android_Play_Store_Search_Icon.png

Thank you

Comment: Correct me if I'm  wrong, but I thought that if your manifest declared an app icon, then that was the icon used for Play and the launcher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not within your control. It is done automatically by Google for popular apps. The only way you can do this is by making your app one of the really popular ones.